# Две связанные опции в 1 БД

Tags: php, sql

**1. Есть страница называется к примеру "Иван Иванов продает машину"**

*структура БД:*

- ID продавца
- Имя и т.п.

**2. Есть страница с марками автомобилей**

*структура БД:*

- Id марки автомобиля,
- Id продавца,
- название марки автомобиля,
- произвольное поле

**3. Как сделать что бы можно было записать в БД 2,3 автомобиля где марка автомобиля это select элемент а input - ссылка?**

(грубо говоря связный список между select и input[text] записать в БД х 2 или 3 раза)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
    var div = $("<div />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
  });
  $("#btnGet").bind("click", function() {
    var values =
      $.map($("input[name=DynamicTextBox]"), function(el) {
        return el.value
      }).join(",\n");
    $("#anotherTextbox").val(values);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("div.row").remove();
  });
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    return `
    <select name="marca">
      <option value="1">BMW</option>
      <option value="2">AUDI</option>
      <option value="3">VW</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="links" value="" placeholder="Ссылка на машину" />`
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
  <button id="btnAdd">Добавить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Какой еще связный список? Какая ссылка, в какой таблице?

Comment: При чем тут SQL, если данные HTML формы нужно обрабатывать в PHP?

Comment: Нажимаешь добавить появляется select + input и POST записать в БД

Comment: Конкретно опишите, что вам непонятно, иначе вопрос нужно будет закрыть как непонятный. Вам непонятно как с PHP работать или как SQL запросы формировать?

Comment: Мне непонятно, как можно отправить 2 строки с одинаковыми полем name

Comment: Приведите код HTML формы, где вы выполняете POST запрос. HTTP запросу без разницы есть ли одинаковые поля.

Comment: Добавил в сообщении, спасибо

Comment: Ну а на бэкэнде как вы POST обрабатываете? Выложите код.

Comment: Почему вы сразу все не выложили?

Comment: В том и дело. что я не знаю как обработать такую форму. что бы каждое поле соответствовало записи в БД (select-input)

Comment: @Выложите код, который вы пытались использовать для обработки формы, покажите свои старания. В какой столбец какой страницы вы хотите сохранять URL?

Comment: Кажется понял, вы не знаете как создать связь один ко многим?